# How Do I Set The Node Version In An Azure Web App?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure

I have created an Azure Web App using terraform but it has the wrong version of NodeJS in it.

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "app-plan" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-app-plan"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.resource_group_location

  sku {
    tier = "Free"
    size = "F1"
  }
}

#azurerm_app_service doesn't support creating Node.JS 8.10 apps
#https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/4144
resource "azurerm_app_service" "app-service" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-app"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.resource_group_location
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.app-plan.id
}
```

I have tried updating the [configuration using the rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdateconfiguration)

```
{
  "properties": {
    "nodeVersion": "8.10"
  }
}
```

and also updating the [application settings using the rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateapplicationsettings)

```
{
  "properties": {
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION": "8.10"
  }
}
```

However, when I run the Console it still says `node --version v0.10.40`

When I run `env` it looks like the `PATH` variable is incorrect.

Node 8.10 does exist on the machine at `D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\8.10.0`

How can I update the path from the rest api?

Are there any alternatives?

My preferences are terraform > az cl > rest api

**Note:**
Bear in mind that when I create the web app in the portal, selecting Node 8.10 forces me to choose Windows as the O/S.

Comment: Readers may get some benefit from browsing and perhaps contributing to the code at:
https://github.com/ourchitecture/patterns-and-tutorials/tree/main/src/tutorials/node/azure#readme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the portal it specifies `Node 8.10` as a Runtime stack.

The az cli specifies `8.10` as a runtime:

```
az webapp list-runtimes|grep "8.10"
"node|8.10",
```

However, as you can see in the question, the version installed is `8.10.0`.

If we set this in the application settings with terraform this (unintuitively) sets the correct node version:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "app-service" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-app"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.resource_group_location
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.app-plan.id

  app_settings = {
    #The portal and az cli list "8.10" as the supported version.
    #"8.10" doesn't work here!
    #"8.10.0" is the version installed in D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION" = "8.10.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Under site_config, linux_fx_version should be set to "NODE|8.10"

I have gotten it to work with node 10.14, using:

```
site_config {
    linux_fx_version = "NODE|10.14"
  }
```

You can also see different examples of azure web apps over at:
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/tree/master/examples/app-service

Answer (score 0):

In **2023** the [`node_version`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_web_app#node_version) is set in the `site_config` stanza of `azurerm_linux_web_app`:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "my-service" {
  ...

  site_config {
    ...

    application_stack {
      node_version = "18-lts"
    }
  }
}
```